# Insert Edge Loop without modifying underlying weights?

Tags: edges, vertex-weights

New to Blender here!

Just a quick one: I'm wondering if it's possible to insert an edge loop on a mesh that already has weights painted without modifying the underlying weights. What I've discovered is that inserting an edge would change the weights corresponding to the newly inserted edge. Is it possible to have the edge exist without having the weights modified? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them untouched, lock all vertex groups before inserting the edgeloop.

In any case the new edge loop will receive its weights from the nearby vertices (but you can remove them, if needed).

[image]